# How do you solve 9k ≡ 3 (mod 21)?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know how to solve it when the GCD is 1, as in "solving 9k≡2 (mod 29). You just use the Euclidean algorithm backward and find what the multiplicative inverse of 9 is. But what is the general solution for the questions like this one where there's no multiplicative inverse?

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem is, in general, the way to go. This particular time there is a simplified version as demonstrated in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$9k\equiv3\pmod{21}\iff3k\equiv1\pmod7$$

Now $3\cdot5\equiv1\pmod7\iff3^{-1}\equiv5$